# Git discard changes to multiple files with glob

Tags: git

How do I discard unstaged changes to multiple files using glob?

Eg. discard changes to all files in `folder1` or matching `filename*`.

Comment: Uncommitted changes of tracked files (ones already added to git)? I would use `git checkout -- filename*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git can do its own glob expansion, or you can let your shell do the glob expansion for Git.

The phrase *discard unstaged changes* suggests that you would like to copy the staged versions back into the work-tree.  In this case, [evolutionxbox's answer in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49207628/git-discard-changes-to-multiple-files-with-glob#comment85425665_49207628) is correct:

```
git checkout -- filename*
```

for instance.  This tells Git to copy files from the index to the work-tree.  It's important to note, though, precisely who or what is expanding `filename*` here.

#### Glob expansion: who expands it?

In a command line shell like sh or bash, it's the *shell* that expands `filename*`.  The shell looks at your work-tree, sees which files match the pattern `filename*`, and ends up running `git checkout` with the expanded result.  For instance, if you have `filename1` and `filenameX`, it's the *shell* that runs:

```
git checkout -- filename1 filenameX
```

and *Git* never sees the glob-character `*`.

In these shells, you can run instead:

```
git checkout -- 'filename*'
```

The quotes here protect the `*` from the shell, so that this passes the literal string `filename*` to Git.  At this point *Git* will expand `filename*`, and it uses a different set of rules: it matches whatever is actually in the index.

This mostly doesn't make any difference.  But suppose that `filename*` matches `filename.py` and `filename.pyc`, when all file names ending in `.pyc` are specifically *ignored*.  The *shell* will find both files in the work-tree and pass both names to Git, and Git will complain that `filename.pyc` doesn't exist in the index and hence Git cannot do a `git checkout` on it.

If you pass the `*` through to *Git*, though, it will look in the index, match `filename.py`, *not see any `filename.pyc`*, and check out just `filename.py`, with no error complaints.

#### Gory details: the three versions and how to copy each around

Remember that in Git, you have three versions of each file active all the time:

- `HEAD:README.txt` is the committed version of `README.txt`, which is forever saved under the current commit's hash ID.
- `:0:README.txt` is another copy of `README.txt` in the *index* aka *staging area* aka *cache*.  (This thing has three names, either because it's hugely important—and it is—or because the name originally chosen is kind of meaningless. :-) )
- `README.txt` is just an ordinary file in your work-tree, where you can actually view and edit it.

The `git add` command simply copies the work-tree version of `README.txt` into the `:0:README.txt` version, so that it's *staged for commit* by being updated in the index.

This kind of `git checkout`, using `-- <names>`, makes Git copy in the other direction: index to work-tree.

If there are *unstaged changes*, that means the work-tree version differs from the staged version.  The staged version starts out matching the `HEAD:` version.  However, if you've run `git add -p` on a file, you can get *all three* versions to differ: the `HEAD:` version is from the current commit, and the staged version is kind of in between that one and the work-tree version.  Using `git checkout -- <name>` will copy the staged version to the work-tree.

You can also copy from the current commit to the index, using `git reset -- <name>`.  This makes the staged version, such as `:0:README.txt`, match the `HEAD:README.txt` version.

And, you can copy from *any* commit to the index using `git checkout HEAD -- <name>`.  When you do this, Git insists on copying the index version to the work-tree as well.

#### Summary

`git add` copies files *from* the work-tree, *to* the staging area (aka index, aka cache).

`git reset -- <path>` copies files *from* the `HEAD` commit, *to* the staging area, without touching the work-tree.  The `-- <path>` part is important.  The `--` is required if and only if some `<path>` looks like a `git reset` option.  Note that this kind of `git reset`, when you give it `<path>` arguments, is quite different from `git reset` without a path!

`git checkout -- <path>` copies files *from* the index / staging-area, *to* the work-tree.  The `--` is required if `<path>` looks like a `git checkout` option *or* if it looks like a branch name (what if you have a file named `master`?), so it's wise to just use it always.

`git checkout <commit-specifier> -- <path>` copies files *from* the specified commit.  You can use `HEAD` here, or any commit hash, or branch name, or tag name, or whatever.  The files go into *both* the index *and* the work-tree at this time.

Note that both of these kinds of `git checkout`, when you give it `<path>` arguments, are very different from `git checkout <branchname>`!

(This tendency that Git has, of stuffing wildly different actions under one verb like `reset` or `checkout`, is a bad idea, but we are kind of stuck with it.  You can use wrappers, e.g., http://www.saintsjd.com/2012/01/a-better-ui-for-git/, but it makes conversing with other Git users difficult.)